# Loop through string on button click Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] quotes = new string[3];
        quotes[0] = "1st quote";
        quotes[1] = "2nd quote";
        quotes[2] = "3rd quote";

        for (int i = 0; i < quotes.Length; i++)
        {
            label.Text = quotes[i];
        }
    }
```

This is my first "test" project with xamarin and I'm trying to figure out how to loop through a string on button click. Also, when a certain "quotes[i]" exists its value is equal to the label.Text in my XAML file. I'm getting confused on when I can use int vs string since this is different from JS.

Comment: the code you've written appears valid - is it not working?  Keep in mind that the loop will execute faster than the UI will update, so you will never see the interim values displayed.

Comment: could you please clarify what are you trying to do even if it was in JS terms

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the variable is not global, so when the user stops clicking on the button their progress resets.

```
private int currentIndex = 0;
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string[] quotes = new string[3];
             quotes[0] = "1st quote";
             quotes[1] = "2nd quote";
             quotes[2] = "3rd quote";

             label.Text = quotes[currentIndex];
             currentIndex++;
             if (currentIndex == 3){
                currentIndex = 0
             }
        }
```

This answer ensures that once the user has clicked thrice it does not crash the program like RippStudwell's answer will.

Comment: Nice copy-paste my mans. You're assuming that's how he wants this to function which is why I didn't include that in my response. And ironically, yours still crashes.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will run through the entirety of your loop every time you click your button. To get what you want, set a global int and increment it after each click instead.

```
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string[] quotes = new string[3];
             quotes[0] = "1st quote";
             quotes[1] = "2nd quote";
             quotes[2] = "3rd quote";

             label.Text = quotes[currentIndex];
             currentIndex++;
        }
```